# carry along URL of server B to server A, and also server C to server A

Tags: php, apache

is it possible to have the following scenario?

I want to maintain `server A` and all images and products details stored in `Server A`.
Then I would like to have link from `server B` and `server C` point to `server A`, BUT, I want the URL still remain as where it comes from.

Scenario Example :

```
1) www.serverC.com -> server A (URL : www.serverC.com/?product_id=123)
2) www.serverB.com -> server A (URL : www.serverB.com/?product_id=123)
```

How can I achieve this?

Noted: i am using PHP, Apache and MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one help you :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.serverC.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.serverA.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: place this in .htacess on which server ?

Comment: You can write the respective server, where you want to redirect from - like if you want to redirect from serverC to serverA, then you can write the above code in serverC

Comment: unfortunately server B and server C is not under my control, as they are partner's server. Only server A is under my control.